# Damped undriven oscillator: $\ddot x + \gamma \dot x + \omega_0^2 x =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the differential equation $\ddot x + \gamma \dot x + \omega_0^2 x =0$, one could assume a solution of the form $e^{\lambda t}$.

The characteristic equation yields 
$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{-\gamma \pm \sqrt{\gamma ^2 - 4\omega_0^2}}{2}.$$

I'm concerned with the case in which $\gamma^2<4\omega_0^2$. Then, if $\lambda=\lambda_1=\lambda_2^*$, the general solution is:

$$x(t) = C_1e^{(\Re(\lambda)+i\Im(\lambda))t}+C_2e^{(\Re(\lambda)-i\Im(\lambda))t} =e^{\Re(\lambda)t}\left[(C_1+C_2)\cos\Im (\lambda) t + i(C_1-C_2)\sin\Im(\lambda)t\right].~\tag{1}$$

Typically in physics when one solves this equation, the assumption $Ae^{-\gamma t/2}\cos(\omega_1t-\phi)$ as a solution is taken, as demonstrated [here](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node10.html). I don't see a clear way to go from $(1)$ to the solution mentioned. Can you help me out with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: what, you don't know eulers formula $e^{i t} = \cos t + i\sin t?$

Comment: @abel, yes but how can I get rid of the terms $(C_1\pm C_2)$?

Comment: choose $C_2 = \bar{C_1}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $C_1=A·e^{iϕ}$ with $A>0$ real. To obtain a real solution, you then necessarily get
$$
C_2=\bar C_1=A·e^{-iϕ}
$$
Combined with your first form of the solution and $λ=-γ/2+iω_1$ you get
$$-
x(t)=A·e^{iϕ}·e^{(-γ/2+iω_1)·t}+A·e^{-iϕ}·e^{(-γ/2-iω_1)·t}
=2A·e^{-γt/2}·\cos(ω_1t+ϕ)
$$
So with a little tweaking in the choice of representing the constants, you can get to the formula with amplitude and phase.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's obvious but, why is it necessary to have $C_2=C_1^*$?

Comment: Because $\overline{x(t)}=x(t)$ for real solutions. The coefficient identity follows from comparing the coefficients of equal exponentials.